# Showing JSON results after parsing it in Swift 3

Tags: json, swift, xcode, uitableview, parsing

I'm trying to parse a JSON with the below code and show it in a table view, but this code runs without any problems or errors, but I'm unable to make it show when I run the app in the sim or even see the JSON results in the debug window.

I'm not using Storyboard. Only working on Swift code. For this I have added the following in the AppDelegate.swift

window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

```
import UIKit

class Post: NSObject {
    var id: String?
    var title: String?
    var year: NSNumber?
    var quote: String?
    var image: String?
    var currency: NSNumber?
    var desc: String?
    var type: String?
}

class FeedController: UITableViewController {

    var posts = [Post]()
    var numberOfRows = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "jsonFile", ofType: "json") {

            do {

                let data = try NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: NSData.ReadingOptions.mappedIfSafe)

                let jsonDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data as Data, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject]

                if let postDictionary = jsonDictionary["post"] as? [String: Any] {
                    let post = Post()
                    post.setValuesForKeys(postDictionary)
                    print(post.mvs_id, post.mvs_plot)

                    numberOfRows = (jsonDictionary["data"]?.count)!


                }


                print(jsonDictionary)


            } catch let err {
                print(err)
            }



        }


    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return numberOfRows
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) 


        return cell
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


}
```

I need help to understand what am I doing wrong to make this parsed JSON show when I run the app, or at least show me the results in the debugger? Thanks

Comment: You need to do `self.tableView.reloadData()` once you parsed the json. Also, you didn't put any code in `cell` to show some text. And, the question is what did mean by "show", show in UI, or the `print(jsonDictionary)`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. What I meant by show is to see something like this when i run the app. So I start working on it's design. https://i.ytimg.com/vi/bU5YR0OMn48/maxresdefault.jpg I will try the line of code your mentioned and report back. Btw I am trying to make a 2 column table.